# Поменять местами первое и последнее слово в предложении

Tags: .net, строки, c++-cli

Как поменять местами первое и последнее слово в предложении? Нужно использовать Replace,IndexOf,LastIndexOf.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    String^ X = textBox1->Text;
    String^ Y = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < X->Length; i--)
    {
        Y = X->Substring(0, X->IndexOf(' '));
        Y = X->Substring(X->LastIndexOf(' '));
    
    }
            MessageBox::Show(Y, "поменять местами", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Что-то такое:

```
Array<String> ^a = X->Split(' ');
String ^s = a[0];
a[0] = a[a->Length - 1];
a[a->Length - 1] = s;
s = String::Join(" ", a);
MessageBox::Show(s, "поменять местами", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);
```